# Odoo: External API: TypeError: cannot marshal <class 'datetime.date'> objects

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

with our slightly modified Odoo (V12), we are trying to fetch Data via external API from odoo.

while fetching res.partner we get following Error:

```
TypeError: cannot marshal <class 'datetime.date'> objects
```

the fetched Object has the following datetime/date values

```
'write_date': datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 16, 11, 56, 51, 417000),
'uid_nr_check': datetime.date(2018, 10, 1),
'__last_update': datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 16, 11, 56, 51, 417000),
```

uid_nr_check is defined as:

```
uid_nr_check = fields.Date(string="last UID Number check")
```

any ideas whats wrong? we use nighly build of odoo 12 on debian.

Comment: Are you getting that error from a remote Odoo instance? or your local instance is producing those values to build a response over xmlrpc and it's producing an error for the xmlrpc client?

Comment: we have an external PHP app that tries to fetch Values from our local odoo. while fetching data via xmprcp- odoo raises this error.  we added some date and datetime fields to res.partner